# Shebang for scripts not working

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I am using PythonAnyhwere for my django production environment. I have a script which should run on scheduled basis.

Since I installed django in a virtualenv, the script starts like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
activate_this = '/home/myname/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

The error I get for this is

```
/usr/bin/env python: no such Python interpreter
```

No problem. So I changed it to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

Then I got

```
/usr/bin/env python2.7: no such Python interpreter
```

or

```
/usr/bin/env python3.4: no such Python interpreter
```

I said ok, what if I don't have a shebang line at all?
Error in log:

```
line 1: activate_this: command not found
line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `activate_this,'
line 2: `execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))'
```

What is the way then?

Comment: Have you tried `$which python` and put output to your shebang?

Comment: No. How could I implement it in my script?

Comment: Just execute it in terminal if you have access to it. Without `$` sign

Comment: The shell says `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Try to put it in shebang and see if it helps

Comment: Nice. It worked! If you could write that down as an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know where your Python interpreter by typing

```
$ which python
```

Also you try something like this (or maybe without `env`):

```
$ env python
Python 3.5.0 (default, Sep 20 2015, 11:28:25) 
[GCC 5.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path
<module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py'>
```

And then change `lib` to `bin` and omit `/posixpath.py` part